# How can this DualPivot Quicksort be made better / faster

Tags: c#, quicksort

How the title already says, im asking how I can make my code faster or better. Right now im having the problem that my Dual Pivot Quicksort is much much slower than a normal Quicksort and also cant handle large numbers as well. Right now im just gonna put in the code for the Method but if you want I can post the Main methode too, so you can see my inputs.

```cs
public static List<int> sort(List<int> input, bool start)
{
    if (input.Count > 1)
    {
        int LP = input[0];
        int RP = input[input.Count - 1];
        List<int> lessLP = new List<int>();
        List<int> greatRP = new List<int>();
        List<int> betweenLPRP = new List<int>();
        if (LP > RP)
        {
            int sp = LP;
            LP = RP;
            RP = sp;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < input.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] < LP)
            {
                lessLP.Add(input[i]);
            }

            else if (input[i] > RP)
            {
                greatRP.Add(input[i]);
            }

            else if (input[i] >= LP & input[i] <= RP)
            {
                betweenLPRP.Add(input[i]);
            }
        }
        List<int> end = new List<int>();

        lessLP = sort(lessLP, false);
        greatRP = sort(greatRP, false);
        betweenLPRP = sort(betweenLPRP, false);
        input.Clear();

        foreach (var x in lessLP)
        {
            end.Add(x);
        }
        lessLP.Clear();
        end.Add(LP);
        foreach (var x in betweenLPRP)
        {
            end.Add(x);
        }
        betweenLPRP.Clear();
        end.Add(RP);
        foreach (var x in greatRP)
        {
            end.Add(x);
        }
        greatRP.Clear();
        return end;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Thanks for helping already.
btw Sorry for the uncommented code

Edit:
Ok after some feedback I tried to get this code https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/dual-pivot-quicksort-reference-implementation
as c# to work.

but everytime I run this code now I get an StackOverflowException

```cs
        public static void quicksort(ref int[] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            if (right > left)
            {
                if (arr[left] > arr[right]) swap(ref arr, left, right);
                int p = arr[left], q = arr[right];

                int l = left + 1, g = right - 1, k = 1; 
                while(k <= g)
                {
                    if (arr[k] < p)
                    {
                        swap(ref arr, k, l);
                        l++;
                    }

                    else if (arr[k] >= q)
                    {
                        while (arr[g] > q && k < g) g--;
                        swap(ref arr, k, g);
                        g--;
                        if(arr[k] < p)
                        {
                            swap(ref arr, k, l);
                            l++;
                        }
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                l--; g++;

                swap(ref arr, left, l);
                swap(ref arr, right, g);
                quicksort(ref arr, left, l - 1);
                quicksort(ref arr, l + 1, g - 1);
                quicksort(ref arr, g + 1, right);
            }
        }

        public static void swap(ref int[] arr, int i, int j)
        {
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
```

Comment: If you have working code and want to improve it, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better site than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your dynamic allocations are killing you here. DP quicksort can be implemented as an in-place sort, which will perform much better. See an example [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/dual-pivot-quicksort-reference-implementation).

Comment: Ok thank you both, I think I updated my question acordingly. I hope you or someone else can help me here. Also how can I like comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your translation of the code from that reference.

On this line:

`int l = left + 1, g = right - 1, k = 1;`

That last `1` (one) that you have should instead be an `l` (lower-case L).

Incidentally, since arrays are reference types by definition in `c#`, the `ref` modifier on the `arr` argument is unnecessary. That is only needed if you wish to replace the entire parameter wholesale from within the method (as in `arr = new ...`) and have that change reflected in the caller. This goes for both `quicksort` and `swap`. Here, `ref` only makes the code less efficient.

Another minor point is that the referenced code (and yours) has some inefficiencies where it calls `swap` with identical `i` and `j` arguments - doesn't affect validity, though, only speed.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with the lower case L typo, and the ref arr. Thats pretty good to know thank you very much have a nice Day